# Azure access blob in directory

Tags: azure, blob

I'm trying to download a pdf blob that is in a directory in a container: folder1/test.pdf.

I've tried the following with no luck and searched for examples, but can't find anything.

```
 // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
            CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

        // Create the blob client.
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("testcontainer/folder1");

        // Retrieve reference to a blob
        //CloudBlockBlob blockBlob2 = container.GetBlockBlobReference("test.pdf");
```

Also tried this:

```
 // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
            CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

        // Create the blob client.
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("testcontainer");

        // Retrieve reference to a blob
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob2 = container.GetBlockBlobReference("folder1/test.pdf");
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see the code to download the blob. BTW, 1st code block is incorrect but the 2nd one is correct.

Comment: Here' the code that does the download:

Comment: I'm not sure how to edit my original post, but this is where i get a 404;  using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            blockBlob2.DownloadToStream(memoryStream);
           ....

Comment: Blob names are case sensitive. That could be the reason for getting 404 error. Please check the name and try your request again. Otherwise your code looks fine. Other reason could be that the container and/or blob does not really exist.

Comment: thanks, Gaurav, it was the case sensitivity.  I did know about this, and thought i tested that, but must have had something else wrong when i tried.